# Создание MySQL таблицы со счетчиком пользователя

Tags: php, mysql

У каждого пользователя на сайте есть свой уникальный код. Так вот, есть определенная функция на сайте и мне нужно вести учет, сколько пользователь раз ею воспользовался. Например он заходит в первый раз, тогда в таблицу заносится новое значение с кодом пользователя и 0 в колонке посещений и каждый последующий раз нужно добавлять 1 к колонке посещения. Также нужно, чтобы эта цифра(посещений) возвращалась на сайт и пользователь видел, сколько раз он использовал функцию.

Comment: Ну так создай таблицу для хранения этих данных (можно и поле в таблице пользователей, но хуже), при каждом обращении к функции выполняй изменение данных (INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE) и тут же запрашивай их для вывода.

Comment: @Akina, я просто не очень знаком с технологиями MySQL и его общения с PHP. Может посоветуете статьи к прочтению?

Comment: В любой книге с основами PHP есть раздел о работе с mysql. Статьи гуглятся по соответствующему запросу.